# Is there any way to slow down hard disc writes on linux?

Tags: linux, storage, stress-testing

I want to anayse influence of slow disc storage on my application. In order to do it I want to decrease writes thougput to the storage. Can I do it by some configuration or is there any tool dedicated for that?

Comment: have a look at [ionice](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ionice)

Comment: Thanks, but ionice only sets priority to process which means no real throughput change if there are no other io consuming processes.

Comment: Yep. That's why it isn't an answer. You can always generate random IO to throttle your application.

Comment: I'll try it if I won't find better option

Answer (score 2):

You could use Linux Kernel [cgroups](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/cgroups.7.html) (*control groups*). See [Throttling IO with Linux](https://www.google.fi/amp/s/fritshoogland.wordpress.com/2012/12/15/throttling-io-with-linux/amp/). Another option is to use virtualization and limit I/O available for the VM. This might be a good setup for testing. For example, QEMU has [DiskIOLimits](http://wiki.qemu.org/Features/DiskIOLimits); this page also has a valuable notice:

> The availability of disk I/O throttling depends on the underlying
>   storage (image file, LVM, NFS, Ceph). On Linux the cgroups
>   blkio-controller supports I/O throttling on block devices but is a
>   relatively recent feature. More importantly, there is no single
>   mechanism for disk I/O throttling across all underlying storage types
>   and for some types there is no way to throttle at all.